# Python 2 vs Python 3 Regex matching behavior

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Python 3

```
import re

P = re.compile(r'[\s\t]+') 
re.sub(P, ' ', '\xa0 haha')
' haha'
```

Python 2

```
import re

P = re.compile(r'[\s\t]+')
re.sub(P, u' ', u'\xa0 haha')
u'\xa0 haha'
```

I desire the Python 3 behavior, but in Python 2 code. How come the regex pattern fails to match space-like codepoints like `\xa0` in Python 2 but correctly matches these in Python 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `re.UNICODE` flag:

```
>>> import re
>>> P = re.compile(r'[\s\t]+', flags=re.UNICODE)
>>> re.sub(P, u' ', u'\xa0 haha')
u' haha'
```

Without the flag, only ASCII whitespace is matched; `\xa0` is not part of the ASCII standard (it is a Latin-1 codepoint).

The `re.UNICODE` flag is the default in Python 3; use [`re.ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) if you wanted to have the Python 2 (bytestring) behaviour.

Note that there is no point in including `\t` in the character class; `\t` is already part of the `\s` class, so the following will match the exact same input:

```
P = re.compile(r'\s+', flags=re.UNICODE)
```